# How to do sentiment analysis with topic modeling or NER [ Python]?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have the following code for sentiment analysis. I was wondering how can I include topic modeling or NER within it? (the dataset is of customers' reviews of 3 websites, a csv file of 2 columns, one the reviews and one the rating of 0 as negative and 1 for positive)

```
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
    
    dataset = pd.read_csv('full_db.csv') 
    X = dataset.iloc[:,0].values
    y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
    
    corpus = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(X)):
        review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset['Review'][i])  #replace punctuations with space
        review = review.lower()  #transfering all the letters to lower-case
        review = review.split()  #spliting the review into words
        #apply stemming
        ps = PorterStemmer()
        all_stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
        no_stopwords = ["not","don't",'aren','don','ain',"aren't", 'couldn', "couldn't", "wasn't"]
        for Nostopword in no_stopwords:
            all_stopwords.remove(Nostopword)
        review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(all_stopwords)] 
        review = ' '.join(review)
        corpus.append(review)

    #Splitting the dataset into Training set and Test set
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    
    #logistic regression
    # Initialize a logistic regression model 
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score,classification_report
    logistic = LogisticRegression(random_state=42, solver='lbfgs',
                                multi_class='multinomial')
    # Train the model
    logistic = logistic.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = logistic.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do NER, Topic Modeling, and Sentiment Analysis in the same model, but I can show you how to do NER and Topic Modeling with two separate models here. I have been working in NLP for a while and wrote both of the articles I pull code from in this answer.

You can use NLTK packages to do NER on your corpus without needing to train an additional model. (Code taken from this article on [Named Entity Recognition](https://pythonalgos.com/the-best-way-to-do-named-entity-recognition-ner/))

Run in Terminal to get the packages:

```py
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download(“punkt”)
>>> nltk.download(“averaged_perceptron_tagger”)
>>> nltk.download(“maxent_ne_chunker”)
>>> nltk.download(“words”)
```

Python:

```
import nltk
 
text = "Molly Moon is a cow. She is part of the United Nations' Climate Action Committee."
 
tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
pos_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
chunks = nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tagged)
for chunk in chunks:
    if hasattr(chunk, 'label'):
        print(chunk)
```

For topic modeling, you can use BERTopic. (Code pulled from this article on [Topic Modeling](https://blog.deepgram.com/python-topic-modeling-with-a-bert-model/)) The `docs` variable should be a list of document text.

```
# creating and fitting model
from bertopic import BERTopic
model = BERTopic()
topics, probs = model.fit_transform(docs)
# plotting model
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from umap import UMAP
 
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
%matplotlib inline
 
# Prepare data for plotting
embeddings = model._extract_embeddings(docs, method="document")
umap_model = UMAP(n_neighbors=10, n_components=2, min_dist=0.0, metric='cosine').fit(embeddings)
df = pd.DataFrame(umap_model.embedding_, columns=["x", "y"])
df["topic"] = topics
 
# Plot parameters
top_n = 10
fontsize = 12
 
# Slice data
to_plot = df.copy()
to_plot[df.topic >= top_n] = -1
outliers = to_plot.loc[to_plot.topic == -1]
non_outliers = to_plot.loc[to_plot.topic != -1]
 
# Visualize topics
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['#FF5722', # Red
                                        '#03A9F4', # Blue
                                        '#4CAF50', # Green
                                        '#80CBC4', # FFEB3B
                                        '#673AB7', # Purple
                                        '#795548', # Brown
                                        '#E91E63', # Pink
                                        '#212121', # Black
                                        '#00BCD4', # Light Blue
                                        '#CDDC39', # Yellow/Red
                                        '#AED581', # Light Green
                                        '#FFE082', # Light Orange
                                        '#BCAAA4', # Light Brown
                                        '#B39DDB', # Light Purple
                                        '#F48FB1', # Light Pink
                                        ])
 
# Visualize outliers + inliers
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
scatter_outliers = ax.scatter(outliers['x'], outliers['y'], c="#E0E0E0", s=1, alpha=.3)
scatter = ax.scatter(non_outliers['x'], non_outliers['y'], c=non_outliers['topic'], s=1, alpha=.3, cmap=cmap)
 
# Add topic names to clusters
centroids = to_plot.groupby("topic").mean().reset_index().iloc[1:]
for row in centroids.iterrows():
   topic = int(row[1].topic)
   text = f"{topic}: " + "_".join([x[0] for x in model.get_topic(topic)[:3]])
   ax.text(row[1].x, row[1].y*1.01, text, fontsize=fontsize, horizontalalignment='center')
 
ax.text(0.99, 0.01, f"BERTopic - Top {top_n} topics", transform=ax.transAxes, horizontalalignment="right", color="black")
plt.xticks([], [])
plt.yticks([], [])
plt.savefig("BERTopic_Example_Cluster_Plot.png")
plt.show()
```